# Rails 5 gem database_cleaner not find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm not new to rails but was a long time I didn't used it. Today was trying to build something and get this.

I try to run a standard

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user:references
```

And I always get this message in the terminal

```
Could not find database_cleaner-1.5.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But when I check in the Gemfile I have

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.rc1', '< 5.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.x'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem "rails-controller-testing", :git => "https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing"
  gem "rspec-rails", "3.5.0.beta3"
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5.3'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I try everything I find in the net. I deleted my `Gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` again. I install the new version of ruby the 2.3.1.

But I can't figured out what to do. If someone can help me with this, would be appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails g migration ...`?

Comment: Do `bundle install | grep database_cleaner` and see what is installed for database_cleaner,

Comment: This is what I got `Using database_cleaner 1.5.3`

Comment: with bundle exec I got the same problem

Comment: Also, try to run your migration as following `bundle exec rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user:references`. It will make sure that you are using the current bundler.

Comment: I did it and nothing change

Comment: Have you tried to open another terminal?

Comment: So I open new terminal and got the same problem but the gem web-console. I install it again do the migration with bundle and now nothing happen in 2 min just waiting.

Comment: @EmanuelQuimper: Does it work now?

Comment: Nop so I closed everything open new terminal rerun my migration and database_cleaner missing again

Comment: With `bundle exec`? For some reason your migrations are looking into a wrong place. If there is a way for you to start from scratch, do it.

Comment: Yes with `bundle exec` thank for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution with the help of someone on Slack. I got my spring always running so I have just need to do `spring stop` and everything work like a charm after.

Thank you all for the help.